# C++ vector allocator error

Tags: c++, c++11, g++

I'm trying  compile with gcc

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>

std::vector < std::string, std::vector < std::vector < int > > > plain;

int main(){
return 0;
}
```

But getting a error:
   error: ‘class std::vector"<"std::__cxx11::basic_string,    std::allocator"<"std::vector"<"int> > >’ has no member named ‘deallocate’

Comment: Perhaps you wanted to use either `std::map` or `std::unordered_map`??. Please see How to [`mcve`](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and some highly recommend [C++ texts](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list). Additionally, the [**`C++ tag`** wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/c%2b%2b/info) also has some good pointers to get you running.

Comment: It's really not that clear how what you 're trying to do in this snippet.
As others pointed out already, the second argument to std::vector must be an allocator, not another std::vector class/instance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `plain` is `std::vector<std::string, NotReallyAnAllocator>` where `NotReallyAnAllocator` is `std::vector < std::vector < int > >`.

A [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) (of anything) is not an allocator and the compiler clearly complains about the fact that it doesn't implement the necessary allocator interface.

I'm not sure what you wanted to achieve, but look into [`std::unordered_map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map) and [`std::map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) if you need key-value containers.